# Where is the test port located on a CVT Jeep patriot 2012 limited 4WD?

Tags: transmission, jeep, cvt-transmission, patriot

I have a CVT in my patriot and want to install a temp gauge without a T-Fitting since it will be more accurate coming from the transmission itself. I can not seem to find the test port on the transmission anywhere... does anyone know where it is located?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the Live Data coming out of the ECM doesn't already have that information for you?

Comment: no, 1) I have no idea how to do that and 2) if it does, wouldn't it be displayed on the cluster or such?

Comment: You need a scanner to be able to do this, but they are relatively cheap. A lot cheaper than putting a temperature gauge in manually. You can get the information through your OBDII port (AKA data link connector - DLC)

Comment: it wasnt too expensive putting a voltmeter in, i think i might just have to use a t fitting, and put it right before my transmission cooler, that would give the most accurate reading i believe